# Can't resize Kali screen because VM Tools don't appear to be running, even though they claim they are

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux, vsphere

I'm running Kali Linux on VSphere. The problem is that I can't resize the Kali screen (it's always tiny) and I can't copy paste from Kali to my main OS. Changing the resolution doesn't help. This seems to be an issue with the VMWare tools but VSphere says

> "VMWare Tools: Running, version:10336 (Guest Managed)"

If I expand it however it says

> "A VMware Tools implementation is installed on the guest operating
>   system, but it is not managed by VMware. The VMware Tools status is
>   unknown."

The installation type is

> "Open VM Tools (open-vm-tools)"

I have tried reinstalling VMWare Tools several times, doesn't seem to help. Neither does rebooting the Kali box. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/256455

Comment: @EricF Neither of those address my question and come off a little passive aggressive. I've been using Kali since it was called Backtrack if that helps any.

Comment: @EricF if you feel there's a straightforward solution to the problem, feel free to post it as an answer